# windows partitions are not visible

Tags: system-installation, mount, filesystem, windows-10, mountpoint

During installation of Ubuntu I do not see any other partition other than the `VDI`  I  have created for Ubuntu installation.

I am using a windows 10 machine and  created `e:\ubuntu.vdi` (40GB) but now it shows nothing except this 42GB.

Screen shot attached.  Kindly advise.

[image: installation screen]

Here is my windows machine drives:

[image: windows drives]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From: [here:](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/video/microsoft-virtual-desktop-infrastructure-vdi-explained.aspx)

> The concept of VDI is to store and run desktop workloads including a Windows client operating system, applications, and data in a server-based virtual machine (VM) in a data center;

And as I see in your screenshot, you are running VirtualBox. So you are simply installing Ubuntu in a virtual environment and in that environment only your 40GB Virtual drive is recognizable to Ubuntu.

It's like you only have a hard drive with the capacity of 40GB. Actually VirtualBox will virtualize every piece of hardware for you. So everything including CPU, Memory, Hard Disk, etc are being managed by VirtualBox. Read more about [Virtualization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtualization).

If you want to share stuff between your Ubuntu and Windows, you should install `virtualbox guest additions` in your Ubuntu guest; Then share a directory using VirtualBox configurations.